# How Rails convert Rails::Application instance method to class method of the MyApp::Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instance-methods, class-method

As I know

```
 MyApp::Application < Rails::Application
```

and

```
 Rails::Application < Engine
   def config #:nodoc:
     @config ||= Application::Configuration.new(find_root_with_flag("config.ru", Dir.pwd))
   end
 end
```

and the config method is an instance method of the Application class but why Can I use

```
  My::Application < Rails::Application
    config.encoding = "utf-8"
    #...
  end
```

Isn't the config method an instance method of My::Application? And I have saw the railscast [Rails Initialization Walkthrough](http://railscasts.com/episodes/299-rails-initialization-walkthrough?view=asciicast) there is something about :

```
module Rails
  class Railtie
    module Configurable
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern
      module ClassMethods
        def method_missing(*args, &block)
          instance.send(*args, &block)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It overrides method_missing so that every class method that is called on this class that isn’t explicitly defined is passed to the instance. This works just like a singleton does, any method called on the class will act as an instance method.But in Rails4 source code I can't find where Module Configurable be used.

And the same question

```
class Engine < Railtie
  def routes
    @routes ||= ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet.new
    @routes.append(&Proc.new) if block_given?
    @routes
  end
end
```

As you can say,the routes methods also an instance method of Engine. But in the routes.rb  of MyApp we define routes is

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do 
  #...
end
```

Again the routes method used as the class method,why? And I try this:

```
MyApp::Application.methods.grep(/routes/)  #=> []

MyApp::Application.singleton_methods.grep(/routes/)  #=> []

MyApp::Application.instance_methods.grep(/routes/)  #=> [:routes]
```

So where's the magic happened?